# Is an led driver needed for simple circuit?

Tags: led, led-driver

I have been working on circuits for a while, and when an LED has been needed I have always just put in the LED with a resistor. I have never really understood the need for an LED driver or what exactly it does.

My co-worker recently told me that I was doing it all wrong, that I should absolutely use an LED driver as it is better for the LED and reduces power consumption.

Is this true? Is an LED driver really needed for a simple low-power indicator circuit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you define as low power.  For most small LEDs used for indication that will draw ~3-10mA, it's common to just use a resistor.  It doesn't make sense to add the complexity and cost of a driver for an LED.  For higher power LEDs, a constant-current driver is sometimes added to avoid wasting too much power.

Since an LED voltage can vary from piece to piece (even of the same type), using a fixed voltage will give a wide range of LED current which is not desirable.  A resistor can be added to allow the voltage to vary somewhat while keeping the current approximately the same.  But using a resistor is usually less efficient than using a driver.  A constant-current driver provides a relatively fixed current level, provided the supply voltage is high enough, without wasting energy in a series resistor.

Answer (score 5):

For a garden variety indicator LED, there is absolutely no need for a specialized driver.

The entire concept of an LED driver only came out quite recently when high-powered LEDs appeared on the market.

Your coworker is either misinformed or pulling your leg.